# How do I combine refs in Vue.js with a ternary expression?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, conditional-operator, ref

Consider the code snippet below:

```
const salesFilter = computed(() => {
  return Object.values(dataset.value).filter((item) => item.category==="Sales")
})
const salesTotalTwo = ref((salesFilter.value.length == 0) ? []:salesFilter.value[0].values)
```

When the app gets mounted, `dataset` is empty, so `salesFilter` returns empty as well. In that case, I want `salesTotalTwo` to return an empty list, but I'd like it to be updated the moment `dataset` starts containing some information. When I run tests, I can see that `salesFilter` behaves as expected, but for some reason `salesTotalTwo` keeps referring to an empty list. Is my approach of combining a ref with a ternary expression just wrong? Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: `salesTotalTwo` should also be computed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because `salesTwo` property is not reactive. You need to make it using a computed property.

Here is a demo-

```js
const { createApp, ref, computed } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const dataset = ref([]);
    const salesFilter = computed(() => {
      return Object.values(dataset.value).filter((item) => item.category === "Sales")
    })
    const salesTotalTwo = computed(() => {
      return salesFilter.value.length == 0 ? [] : salesFilter.value[0]
    })
    const setDataset = () => {
      dataset.value.push({
        category: "Sales"
      })
    }
    return {
      dataset,
      salesFilter,
      salesTotalTwo,
      setDataset
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  salesTotalTwo - {{ salesTotalTwo }} <br>
  <button @click="setDataset">Set dataset</button>
</div>
```